# Counting messages in a channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am looking for a way to count the messages in a channel through the use of an app/connector/bot or by any other means. I also want to see how many messages a team member has sent in a channel. I've tried looking for apps but I haven't found anything useful. Any suggestions/recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using MS Flow/Power Automate with [Get message] connection?
See the screenshot below.

[image]